# Cannot get into account or contact support

Tags: heroku

My phone was stolen and I no longer have access to 2fa. How / where can I contact support? All links direct to a page that's locked behind a login, which I cannot get past.

Reset my password, searched for details on support pages.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because [we literally cannot help](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/354577). Contact Heroku support. Create a new account if you have to. (Note that this is exactly what MFA is supposed to do. If you can't provide a token, you can't log in. In the future I strongly suggest that you configure an alternate MFA source and / or save your recovery codes.)

Comment: Unfortunately your question is not suitable here

Comment: Whoever upvoted this needs to read [Is it wrong to use an upvote to balance out a downvote?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/311406/354577) This is objectively off topic.

Answer (score -1):

I was having a similar issue and it is nearly impossible to find help through Heroku without logging in (can't file a ticket unless you are logged in), which complicates the issue.

I did find a form that can be filled out to help with account lockout https://www.heroku.com/account-lockout